# Android fill array with ImageViews

Tags: android, listview, imageview, drawable, android-arrayadapter

I want an array of imageviews, but I don't know how to fill it with an object of type imageview.

```
 ImageView[] forAdapter = new ImageView[imageIds.size()];
 for(int i = 0; i < imageIds.size(); i++)
 {
                    ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(context);
                    forAdapter[i] = mImageView.setImageDrawable(((imagesPulled.get(imageIds.get(i)))));
}
```

this doesn't work because `.setImageDrawable` does not return an imageview, and I dont know of any object that actually does!

I considered using drawables in an array, but I'm ultimately setting an arrayadapter for a listview, and I cant make a R.layout with drawables (I'll get a class cast exception because the xml file is using an ImageView not drawable type),so I only have ImageViews to put into an array - unless I'm approaching the problem wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mImageView is ImageView itself.

So,  forAdapter[i] = mImageView should work fine. If you use additional actions, you can do them before assignment.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is almost there! I'm just gonna make a small change and comment on it below:

```
 ImageView[] forAdapter = new ImageView[imageIds.size()];
 for(int i = 0; i < imageIds.size(); i++)
 {
                    forAdapter[i] = new ImageView(context);
                    forAdapter[i].setImageDrawable(imagesPulled.get(imageIds.get(i)));
}
```

First: If you want to initialize forAdapter[i], you don't need to create a new variable and assign it to it. Just do it there:

```
forAdapter[i] = new ImageView(context);
```

Setting the image (using setImageDrawable, setImageResource, etc) doesn't return anything. It's an operation you do on the image itself so all you gotta do is call the method from the variable you  want to modify:

```
forAdapter[i].setImageDrawable(imagesPulled.get(imageIds.get(i)));
```

You're done :)
If you have any doubts just ask in the comments.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, yes I got it to work. Ended up changing things around a bit for a custom array adapter. I was trying to skip the custom array adapter despite its flexibility